# 12.04 Upgrade to Original Wubi 11.10 Dual Boot With Win7 Now Incomunicato

Tags: 12.04

Wubi 11.10 dual boot install on my Win7 C60 AMD64 Acer Aspire One 722 was working well enough, but after using the upgrade button to 12.04 the network connection fails any connect at all, saying to the effect that the hardware is not recognized.  On subject machine I may have neglected to complete the 11.10 updates before running the upgrade to 12.04.

The questions please are how can I back out of this upgrade to Wubi, since with no network connection one may not do over the wire repairs?  Or lacking that back out, might one repair this from an ISO file of 12.04? Or lacking all, how may one back out of the Wubi altogether and go back to the Win7 only boot, since the 12.04 ISO file is running well as a boot under VM Virtual Box under the Win7?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the online upgrade is guaranteed to work in a Wubi install.  I seem to recall that it does not get thoroughly tested during beta testing.  A failure in the on-line upgrade can result in the data on the Wubi install being inaccessible.

You could boot off the LiveDVD of 12.04 (or other) and mount the wubi virtual drive to get your data off it.  You should then remove the wubi install from Windows and re-install 12.04, then put your data back on /home.

You could also consider a dual boot installation of Ubuntu.  Before setting up a dual boot system I recommend that you defrag and check your Windows file system as it can speed up the install (re-partitioning) immensely and greatly reduce the chance of problems.  You really should back up all your data before you do any of this.  If you want to backup the wubi virtual disk before proceeding, you will find it at

d:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk

Chris

Comment: Good info, thanks.  Ended up learning this and the  below processes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as VirtualBox is working well enough for you, I would recommend uninstalling Wubi.

According to the [WubiGuide](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide), you should just be able to [uninstall Wubi](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation) as you would any other Windows application. You can also uninstall by running `C:\ubuntu\Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe`.

Do not forget to save any data of value to you from your Wubi install before you remove it.

Comment: Good info, thanks.  Ended up learning this and the above, have a Wubi and a dusl boot for the exercise.